# How to get more data with twitteR timeline

Tags: r, twitter

I need to export the twitter timeline of 100 users and I need all the tweets from 2014. 
I'm using R for the first time and I was able to run the timeline function and retrieve all the last N tweets of a single user. The problem is that I need more data, such as the timestamp, the number of retweets, the number of favs ecc. 
How can I do it?
The function I used is:

```
userTimeline('username', n=200, maxID=NULL, sinceID=NULL, includeRts=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all there:

```
library(twitteR)
# ... authorize ...
tl <- userTimeline('lukeanker', n=6)
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(tl, function(x) x$toDataFrame()))
names(df)
# [1] "text"          "favorited"     "favoriteCount" "replyToSN"     "created"       "truncated"     "replyToSID"   
# [8] "id"            "replyToUID"    "statusSource"  "screenName"    "retweetCount"  "isRetweet"     "retweeted"    
# [15] "longitude"     "latitude"

df[, c("created", "retweetCount")]
#               created retweetCount
# 1 2015-03-05 13:50:44            0
# 2 2015-02-19 15:51:47            0
# 3 2015-02-17 17:36:01            0
# 4 2015-02-17 17:35:03            0
# 5 2015-02-12 16:49:29            0
# 6 2015-02-11 10:29:35            0
```

Answer (score 1):

or, other way to it is

get @HillaryClinton tweets with all info. up to max of 3200

```
clinton_tweets <- userTimeline("HillaryClinton", n = 3200)
```

A function to convert twitteR lists to data.frames

```
tweetsc.df <- twListToDF(clinton_tweets)
```

then just open the tweetsc.df and see all results